# cocos2d-x Facebook integration (couldn't save which view has focus because the focused view)

Tags: java, facebook, cocos2d-x

I just trying to login with Facebook in my app.
And my app crash with this error "couldn't save which view has focus because the focused view org.cocos2dx.lib.Cocos2dxGLSurfaceView@405ed960 has no id"
Here is my code of Facebook integration:

```
public class wtpbgamazon extends Cocos2dxActivity{
    private Cocos2dxGLSurfaceView mGLView;
    private static Chartboost cb;


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        PurchasingManager.registerObserver(new amazonobserver());

        // start Facebook Login



        Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

            @Override
            public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {

                if (session.isOpened()) {

                      // make request to the /me API
                      Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                        // callback after Graph API response with user object
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                          if (user != null) {
                           //todo
                          }
                        }
                      });
                    }

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        Log.v("onActivityResult Was Called", "good");
      super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
      Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

Can somebody help me with this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I recently Integrated FB in my game. I opened another activity instead of handling FB code in main activity.